# Silverlight: Client/Server tier necessary?

Tags: .net, silverlight

I am coming from a WPF / Windows application background and am learning Silverlight/Web.
The first thing that really confuses me are the tiers. In Windows applications, you have a clear separation between clients - that need to be deployed on each users machine - that in turn talk to the Windows Service/Web service. The latter then in turn talks to the database to retrieve the requested data.

In Silverlight everything seems to be easier. There are no clients to be deployed, the users just open a browser and enter the url address and finished.  At the hosting point where my silverlight app lives too, I could just talk directly to the service assembly locally without having to put it separately on a different web service, correct? Or am I missing a point here?

Many Thanks for advice,
Kave

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Silverlight, the Silverlight application *is* the client. Generally speaking, the Silverlight application communicates with the server from whence it was downloaded. So the web server hosts components for allowing communications with clients, and it hosts the client binaries themselves.

Reading between the lines, I think what you might be missing is the fact that the Silverlight application is *downloaded* to the client machine and run there. In order for it to communicate back to the server, it needs some means of doing so (RIA services, for example).

Comment: Thanks Kent, now I am getting closer. 1) How do you design your silverlight application to talk to your database? What layers do you design? 2) And I read that WCF RIA services is a new technology introduced and it seems to be more utilised for RAD like prototypes, with quick drag and drop creation of the service sitting as a static resource within XAML. Would you recommend it for enterprise applications? Or how would you do this? Many Thanks

Comment: @Kave, you can use the same web service layer used by your WPF applications.

Comment: @Kave: Other questions that aren't minor requests for clarification of an answer to an existing question should be asked using another question rather than attempt to handle them in a limited comment format.

Answer (score 0):

In Silverlight the Silverlight application you develop is the client and gets deployed and execute on Silverlight platform installed on client machine. So conceptually its no different from WPF and you can use WCF to access your web services This [FAQ](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/167001.aspx) gives more detail on this.